# Vue Cannot read property '$root' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I do have the following code in my `main.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './components/App';
import router from './router';

const app = new Vue({
  data: { loading: false },
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Now i try to set the loading var from my router (`./router/index.js`):

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    this.$root.loading = true;
    next();
})

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    this.$root.loading = false;
    next();
})
```

but it doesn't work. I always get

```
Cannot read property '$root' of undefined
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `this` in next callback because the guard is called before the navigation is confirmed, thus the new entering component has not even been created yet.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    //vm refers to this
    next((vm)=>{vm.$root.loading = true;});
})

router.afterEach((to, from, next) => {
    next((vm)=>{vm.$root.loading = false;});
})
```

Comment: Ok, i was happy too early ;-) `router.afterEach` has no next function

Comment: Yes you're right aftereach doesn't have next callback https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-aftereach

Comment: But how to set `$root.loading` to `false` when i cannot call `next` ?